# How to set options in embedding youtube video

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I'm embedding a youtube video. I want to set the following:

```
Control Bar:
show
hide
auto hide

AutoPlay/Use Click to Play
Loop/Play Once
Show/Hide Title Bar
Use Light Control Bar


<object width="425" height="350" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ahg6qcgoay4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ahg6qcgoay4" /></object>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you tried to search on google?
First link I found:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: sorry, I didn't. This is an urgent I need an expert to teach me how to do it. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Posting as seperate answer since I couldn't get code tags to work in comments.

Well just to get you started you can pass those parameters as GET. Consider :
  `src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"`
  now look at the url of the video, suppose you want to hide the controls, go to the link and read details about parameters. You can see a variable named "controls" and it can have two values, 0(hide) and 1(show). So to simply remove the controls change the url of the video like this :
  `src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com&controls=0"` Noticed the variable passed after "&" sign? You can pass multiple variables like this. Hope I kept it simple.

Comment: is there a way to make it an attribute instead as part of the url? eg. autoplay="1"